# Regex.Match double consonants in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of many words. What I need is to find all words ending on "ing", "ed","ied" and with a single vowel and doubled consonant before:
Should match words: begged, slamming, zagging. Not match helping ("lp"-not double consonant)

```
\w*[^aoyie][aoyie]([^aoyie])\1(ed|ing|ied)
```

It's working on RegexPal.com, but it is not working in C# (not matches any words, returns 0 words in list)

My code:

```
List<Book_to_Word> allWords = (from f in db2.Book_to_Words.AsEnumerable() select f).ToList();

List<Book_to_Word> wordsNOTExist = (from f in allWords
                        where Regex.IsMatch(f.WordStr, @"^(\w*[^aoyie]+[aoyie]([^aoyie])(ed|ing|ied))$")
                                    select f).ToList();
```

Works when I don't use \1. But returns words with single consonant.

Comment: On regexpal.com if I put in the above regex it does not match begged or zagging. It needs the modification suggested by nhahtdh to do so.

Comment: And can you clarify what doesn't work about using \1? Does it just not return things or do you get a compile error, does it throw an exception...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nhahtdh.
The problem was in outside parentheses. When I removed them it worked:

```
Regex.IsMatch(f.WordStr, @"^\w*[^aoyieu]+[aoyieu]([^aoyieu])\1(ed|ing|ied)$")
```

Comment: Try testing that against `zigzagging` and it will fail (though shouldn't as I understand it) - With your expression you are saying there can be no vowels apart from the one just before the double consonant. nhahtdh's answer fixes that for you. It should also be noted that you could have kept the outer parentheses and used \2 instead if you wanted.

Comment: You right. Updated to Regex.IsMatch(f.WordStr, @"^\w*[^aoyieu]+[aoyieu]([^aoyieu])\1(ed|ing|ied)$"). Now it's matching zigzagging

Comment: @Vildan: `\w` will make "45435egging" or "_pp_pping" a match. But if they never occurs in the data, then it's fine to use.

Answer (score 6):

Try to relax the condition a bit:

```
@"^[a-z]*[aoyie]([^aoyie])\1(ed|ing|ied)$"
```

Your current regex will require the word to have at least 3 characters before the double consonant and the suffix. So "begged" and "zagging" are not matched.

It is a bit weird, though, to see "y" in the group, while "u" is missing (e.g. "mugged"). You probably want to double check about that. And I have a bit of doubt about double consonant before "ied", but I'll leave it there.

Comment: i think, that Vildan said about `\1`. Check it, please. C# (like all languages except `perl`) supports not flexible version of regular expressions

Comment: @loldop: Back-reference is supported in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx

Comment: I changed question on [^aoyie][aoyie]([^aoyie])\1(ed|ing|ied) - but still not working

Comment: Have you escaped the \ properly in your code? The following works for me and prints out true... `var regex = new Regex("[a-z]*[aoyie]([^aoyie])\\1(ed|ing|ied)");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Begging"));`

Comment: @nhahtdh: edit that into your answer so it can be suitably accepted. :) ( not that I have control over what is accepted)